# DNS issue with specific IP's with Amazon EC-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have a really annoying bug:

for myself and a few of my friends my site is working perfectly.

However, I have heard that for other peope the domain isn't working, but the public IP is.

So I figured it has something to do with the DNS settings, but I followed Amazon's tutorial.

This is what I've set up in amazon:

Domain @ route 53 with 1 hosted zone:

```
domain.com. A 54.187.233.158 - - 300

domain.com. NS

- ns-442.awsdns-55.com. 
- ns-1273.awsdns-31.org. 
- ns-1608.awsdns-09.co.uk.
- ns-863.awsdns-43.net.
- 172800

domain.com. SOA ns-1273.awsdns-31.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400 - - 900

www.domain.com. A 54.187.233.158
```

The records point to the Elastic IP which is assigned to the instance.

In the security groups of the instance I have allowed all traffic on http and https (even though I'm not using https) from all ip's.
Can someone see what I am missing?

Comment: so what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your A record. `Dig`ging your domain, I'm not able to see that A record returned from Amazon's name servers.

```
$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net A florinapp.com   

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @a.gtld-servers.net A florinapp.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42299
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;florinapp.com.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
florinapp.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-442.awsdns-55.com.
florinapp.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-863.awsdns-43.net.
florinapp.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-1608.awsdns-09.co.uk.
florinapp.com.      172800  IN  NS  ns-1273.awsdns-31.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-442.awsdns-55.com.   172800  IN  A   205.251.193.186
ns-863.awsdns-43.net.   172800  IN  A   205.251.195.95

;; Query time: 125 msec
;; SERVER: 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep  5 15:33:12 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 200
```

This shows your domain is registered with Amazon, so now we can recursively query the nameservers returned in the authority section.

```
$ dig @ns-442.awsdns-55.com A florinapp.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns-442.awsdns-55.com A florinapp.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56022
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;florinapp.com.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
florinapp.com.      900 IN  SOA ns-1273.awsdns-31.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 129 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.193.186#53(205.251.193.186)
;; WHEN: Fri Sep  5 15:33:31 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

The response from Amazon doesn't contain any A records, even though we're querying the authoritative nameserver.

Are you sure the A record is configured in Route53?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed it to *.domain.com to see if that works. I had the A records of domain.com and www.domain.com point to the Elastic IP.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've finally figured it out:

I need to have a A record without any prefix, like domain.com. and then one with the `*` wildcard, like *.domain.com.

It's funny that Amazon's docs don't mention this as a probable solution if your DNS isn't working 100%.

Comment: This was downvoted with no explanation. I am currently trying to understand how to hook up a Route 53 DNS to an EC2 Elastic IP and am finding little clarification online. Explanation for down votes would at illustrate directions for me not to go in.